# Proper word wrap in Emacs window

Tags: emacs

I am `text-mode` and `auto-fill-mode` for a buffer. But it still breaks lines in the middle of words, on characters, not words. I'd think there is an easy way to force a buffer to do proper word wrapping, can anyone advise? I've seen questions that suggest various options for changing the `.emacs` config but I can't imagine there is no way to on-the-fly force a word wrap?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. By default, auto-fill-mode will break between words, not within words. Something in your config must be interacting.

Comment: @Tyler in any case, visual-line-mode solved the issue. who knows. I am using Lisp in a Box, a popular pre-configured emacs setup. The actual emacs app is launched by this bundle with no init file, so if there is a conflict, it would have to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try

```
M-x visual-line-mode
```

Comment: But I remember there is some different than simply "wrap by word", for example, `C-e` will move cursor to the end of visual line, not real one